# convert mixed date with int and string to date

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe with a column of dates. the date format is "mixed" with integers and string, like: " 15 January 2000". i would like to have a column with a date like "2000-01-15"

```
list_dates = ['15 January 2000', '16 January 2000', '17 January 2000']
df_dates = pd.DataFrame(list_dates)

df_dates['expect'] = ['2000-01-15', '2000-01-16', '2000-01-17']
```

I expect a column like "df_dates['expect']". Thank you for help!

Comment: `df_dates['expect'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dates['date'])` ??

Comment: Use pd.to_datetime with correct format: `pd.to_datetime(df_dates[0], format="%d %B %Y")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df_dates['expect'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dates['date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
from datetime import datetime

new_values = []
for d in df_dates[0].values:
    dt = datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y')
    new_values.append(f'{dt.year}-{dt.month}-{dt.day}')
df_dates[0] = new_values
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function.

You are looking for the function:

```py
df_dates["expect"] = pd.to_datetime(df_dates["column_name"])
```

A code snippet is shown below:

```py
import pandas as pd

list_dates = ['15 January 2000', '16 January 2000', '17 January 2000']
df_dates = pd.DataFrame(list_dates)
df_dates['expect'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dates[0])
print(df_dates)
```

Output:

```
                 0     expect
0  15 January 2000 2000-01-15
1  16 January 2000 2000-01-16
2  17 January 2000 2000-01-17
```